# How to get average of last 5 rows in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mean

I am monitoring a few hundred user activity online and trying to get average records posted for the last 5 rows (ignoring the missing dates in between). I am using `Window.partitionBy` to partition between users and `rowsBetween` to get the last 5 records but instead of giving me average of the last 5 records for each subsequent rows it seems to include all other rows into the average.

This is what I have tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

win = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy(f.col('record_date')).rowsBetween(-5, 0)

test = df.sort(
  f.asc('record_date')
).withColumn(
  'last5_avg', f.mean('total').over(win)
)
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

This is the result I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to do `(-4, 0)`:

```
win = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy(f.col('record_date')).rowsBetween(-4, 0)
```

because you want to include 5 rows, not 6 rows. Note that the range is inclusive.