# Get last N month average in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with sales dataset for 4 months where I need to calculate last 3 month sales average.

This is what it is supposed to look like. So for September for a given sales rep, L3M should be Sales of (June + July + August) / 3, if for a given rep there's no data entries for say July then it should just be (June + August) / 2.

How can I best do this in pyspark?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get average of last 5 rows in a PySpark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329937/how-to-get-average-of-last-5-rows-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: I don't just want to average based on number of rows, I first want to aggregate it at month level then use the rowBetween on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's the best solution, but I've tried something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"Date": "2022-06-03", "Month": "202206", "Sales": 50, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-06-19", "Month": "202206", "Sales": 10, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-06-27", "Month": "202206", "Sales": 60, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-07-02", "Month": "202207", "Sales": 0, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-08-05", "Month": "202208", "Sales": 30, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-08-09", "Month": "202208", "Sales": 10, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-09-03", "Month": "202209", "Sales": 70, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
    {"Date": "2022-09-07", "Month": "202209", "Sales": 20, "Store_ID": 555, "Sales_Rep": 211},
]
month_window = Window.partitionBy(["Store_ID"]).orderBy("Month_tmp").rangeBetween(-3, -1)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
df_grouped = df.groupBy(["Store_ID", "Month"]).agg(F.sum("Sales").alias("average"))
df_grouped = df_grouped.withColumn("Month_tmp", F.month(F.to_date("Month", "yyyyMM")))
df_grouped = df_grouped.withColumn("tmp", F.count("average").over(month_window))
df_grouped = df_grouped.withColumn("L3M", F.round(F.sum("average").over(month_window) / F.col("tmp"), 2))
df = (
    df.alias("df")
    .join(df_grouped.alias("df2"), df.Month == df_grouped.Month)
    .select("df.Date", "df.Month", "df.Sales", "df.Sales_Rep", "df.Store_ID", "df2.L3M")
)
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()
```

Which gives:

```
+----------+------+-----+---------+--------+-----+                              
|Date      |Month |Sales|Sales_Rep|Store_ID|L3M  |
+----------+------+-----+---------+--------+-----+
|2022-06-03|202206|50   |211      |555     |null |
|2022-06-19|202206|10   |211      |555     |null |
|2022-06-27|202206|60   |211      |555     |null |
|2022-07-02|202207|0    |211      |555     |120.0|
|2022-08-05|202208|30   |211      |555     |60.0 |
|2022-08-09|202208|10   |211      |555     |60.0 |
|2022-09-03|202209|70   |211      |555     |53.33|
|2022-09-07|202209|20   |211      |555     |53.33|
+----------+------+-----+---------+--------+-----+

root
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Month: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sales: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Sales_Rep: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Store_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- L3M: double (nullable = true)
```

I'm also not sure how well will this perform on the full data, but it gives you an example of how to use `groupBy`, `rangeBetween`, and `Window` to isolate the data you need.